# Steam missing libc.so.6 Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy

Tags: apt, 22.04, steam

**Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6**

- `/lib32/libc.so.6` it does exist
- steam was working within the same boot session
- I personally made no change to steam or libc.so.6 prior to this issue

This is the error that I have received recently.
I have tried Uninstall/Reinstalling steam via apt and the error still appears

I have successfully installed and run via the `snap --beta steam` but my prior steam library is on a separate hard drive and I cannot get this version of steam to map there and not to be fussy but that is where I prefer to have it

**Terminal output**

```
(base) My-desktop:~$ steam
steam.sh[147156]: Running Steam on ubuntu 22.04 64-bit
steam.sh[147156]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[147226]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[147156]: Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6
steam.sh[147156]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
(base) My-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1:i386
```

Comment: I have added some code tags to your answer; could you then add a little more detail / background / interpretation / explanation to your answer?